# Is everyone who dies in his 50s Chayav Kares?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rabbis, death, karet, masechet-moed-katan

I've come across a bunch of great Rabbanim: Poskim, Mekubalim and Tzadikim who passed away within their 50s.

The Gemara in **[Moed Katan 28a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.28a.8?lang=bi)** says:

> אמר רבה: [מיתה] מחמשים ועד ששים שנה זו היא מיתת כרת.
>   מת בחמשים שנה זו היא מיתת כרת חמשים ושתים שנה זו היא מיתתו של שמואל הרמתי ששים זו היא מיתה בידי שמים
>
> If one dies when he is fifty years old, this is death through [karet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kareth) [the divine punishment of excision, meted out for the most serious transgressions]

Rashi says: "מחמשים שנה - ולמעלה" it includes all 50s.

Does it make sense to say that these "holy men" were Chayav Kares?

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense that people die for numerous reasons.

Comment: What do you mean @Dr.Shmuel

Comment: all cats are mammals, not all mammals are cats.

Comment: note, even if taking it literally  within 50 is specifically *not* 50

Comment: @menachem the quote above is phrased correctly for the question. "If one dies when he's 50 years old, this is the death through Kares"

Comment: In the passage you quoted, it mentions that Shmuel Haramasi (Shmuel Hanavi) passed away at 52. So he's one exception, and there are others too. (In fact, see Shaarei Tshuva of R' Yona Gerondi: אבל יש צדיקים שמספר ימיהם פחות מששים. כמו שאמרו בן חמשים ושתים זו היא מיתתו של שמואל הרמתי (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd dare to deal with this question epistemologically (?):

1. Kores is a branch of Mitah BiYadey Shamayim - that is decided on exclusively by the Heavenly court (not the Earthy Beis Din).
2. Let's imagine G-d comes down and testifies that all people who died in their 50s were Chayovim Kores. Would you be truly surprised? I wouldn't.
3. If in G-d's terms "dying before 60" means "Kores" so be it, that's Kores de-jure - by its definition and not [what we would expect de-facto]! A completely different question would be - WHY?
4. I'd suggest two possible scenarios:

   1. "פוקד עוון אבות על בנים" - *some* may suffer the consequences of their accedences' sins
   2. Some may suffer from a "*differential punishment"* - Tzadikkim are judged more severely than the laymen, so in G-d's eyes they might override the bar that G-d set for them.
   3. *A very distant option* - some might have actually committed serious sins in private we're not aware of.

Comment: I thought people who are punished for their ancestors' sins have to be evil doers  themselves (i.e. continuing to follow in their ancestors' ways), as Rashi explains to Shemos 34:7